# Stream Java – поиск максимального значения свойства для каждой группы объектов

Tags: java, java-ee, java-stream, java-8

Есть list объектов:

```
SuvLogDto{
private String system;
private Date dateTime;
private String x;
...
}
```

Из этого листа нужно выбрать элементы у которых `dateTime` будет максимальной в его группе, образованной по свойству `system`.

По сути нужно сделать группировку по `system`, а потом внутри образовавшихся групп выбрать максимальный по `dateTime` элемент.

Как пытаюсь это сделать:

```
Map<String, SuvLogDto> mostExpensives = suvLogDtos.stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(SuvLogDto::getSystem, Function.identity()),
                    BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(SuvLogDto::getDateTime)));
```

Это должно подойти, потому что:

```
<T,K,U> Collector<T,?,Map<K,U>> toMap(
                                  Function<? super T,? extends K> keyMapper,
                                  Function<? super T,? extends U> valueMapper,
                                  BinaryOperator<U> mergeFunction)
```

> keyMapper: функция сопоставления для создания ключей сопоставления для
> каждого элемента входного потока. valueMapper: функция сопоставления
> для создания значений сопоставления для каждого элемента входного
> потока. mergeFunction: бинарный оператор, предназначенный для
> разрешения коллизий между значениями, связанными с одним и тем же
> ключом. Входными данными для этой функции являются значения,
> принадлежащие одному и тому же ключу.

Но Java мне выдает ошибку:

> Cannot resolve method
> 'collect(java.util.stream.Collector<T,capture<?>,java.util.Map<K,U>>,
> java.util.function.BinaryOperator)'

Что не так в алгоритме? Как можно поправить?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас в коде небольшая опечатка, так как скобка закрыта *до того* как был указан третий аргумент в коллекторе `toMap`, должно быть так:

```java
List<SuvLogDto> suvLogDtos = Arrays.asList(
    new SuvLogDto("sys1", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 1000), "1 - 1000"),
    new SuvLogDto("abc", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000), "abc-2000"),
    new SuvLogDto("sys1", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 2000), "1 - 2000"),
    new SuvLogDto("xyz", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 3000), "xyz - 3K"),
    new SuvLogDto("abc", new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() - 500), "abc - 500")
);

Map<String, SuvLogDto> mostExpensives = suvLogDtos
    .stream()
    .collect(Collectors.toMap(
        SuvLogDto::getSystem, 
        Function.identity(),
        BinaryOperator.maxBy(Comparator.comparing(SuvLogDto::getDateTime))
    ));

mostExpensives.forEach((k, v) -> System.out.println(k + ": " + v));
```

Вывод результата:

```
sys1: SuvLogDto[system=sys1, date=Fri Sep 16 17:08:53 GMT 2022, x=1 - 1000]
abc: SuvLogDto[system=abc, date=Fri Sep 16 17:08:53 GMT 2022, x=abc - 500]
xyz: SuvLogDto[system=xyz, date=Fri Sep 16 17:08:51 GMT 2022, x=xyz - 3K]
```

Также можно дополнительно указать `LinkedHashMap::new` в качестве четвертого аргумента, чтобы получить мапу, поддерживающую порядок вставки (если нужно).

Comment: Скобочка не в том месте была ))